# I have a question,an error occured in my code saying TIMSK was not declared in the scope(There are no errors)

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, arduino-motor-shield, compilation-errors, board

```
#include <SmartInventor.h>



void setup() {
  SmartInventor.DCMotorUse();




}
void loop() {
  // M1, M2, M3
  // CW, CCW, STOP
  // 0-100
  // 0-360

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(5000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);  //Music starts  //0:00:06
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(11000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0); //Music stops   //0:00:32
  delay(10000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(5000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);
  delay(1000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10); //Music starts back up    //0:00:44
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(18000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);
  delay(3000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 10);
  delay(8000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10); //Music stops   //0:01:15
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(5000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(3000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0); //Music starts up agian   //0:01:31
  delay(11000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0); //Music stops     //0:02:03
  delay(23000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0); //Music starts up agian   //0:02:14
  delay(12000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(6000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(6000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CCW, 10); //Music Ends    //0:02:40
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M1, STOP, 0);
  delay(3000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(5000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000)

  ;SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(13000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(13000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(13000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000)

  ;SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CCW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, CW, 10);
  delay(2000);

  SmartInventor.DCMotor(M2, STOP, 0);
  delay(7000);



}
```

Comment: A different user asked the same question a few days ago. Are you this user? As written in the comments for these questions, you should always include the full error message into the question. "There are no errors" is just wrong, simce you mention the error right before that

Comment: For which board are you compiling the code? And provide a link to the smartinventory library

Comment: The SmartInventor library is only for the Rokit Smart board. Why are you trying to use it with an Arduino Mega?

Answer (score 1):

The SmartInventor library is to be used with the Rokit Smart board. That board is based around the ATMega32.

The Arduino Mega is *not* a Rokit Smart board, so the library will not work, since the Arduino Mega us based around the ATMega2560. The two chips are different, and have different sets of internal peripherals. So the registers have different names accordingly.

Comment: Ok so what board can I use for Rokit smart

Comment: The Rokit Smart.

Comment: Im just gonna write a new code for the mega2560 Arduino board. Can you guys tell me how to write the same code that I did with Rokit smart but in  the Arduino language

Comment: That all depends what it is you are trying to do, and what you are trying to do it to.

Comment: can I code of this typehttps://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=coding+two+dc+motors&&view=detail&mid=A6D70717250191472167A6D70717250191472167&&FORM=VRDGAR&ru=%2Fvideos%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcoding%2520two%2520dc%2520motors%26qs%3Dn%26form%3DQBVR%26sp%3D-1%26pq%3Dcoding%2520two%2520dc%2520motors%26sc%3D0-20%26sk%3D%26cvid%3D6A02585DECEB4033ADC28846E118035B for the mega board

Comment: Probably. Again: what are you trying to control? The Mega is just the brain. You must have something connected to it.

Comment: 3 DC motors. But is 1 and 3 the same thing like Rokit smart? If it is than ill code 2 motors on one board and the other motor on another board.

Comment: No clue. How are you connecting the motors? You must have since kind of motor shield. I suggest you start by looking at the examples given by the manufacturer of that shield.

Comment: Yah I do have a motor shield